# Count the ocurrences of a value in a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with movies as rows and users as columns. Each cell has a rating, a numerical value that ranges from 0 to 2. I want to count the total occurrences in the table that are assigned with the value 0. How can I achieve this?

Example of the dataframe:

```
Movie |User 1|User 2|User 3
MovieX|0     |1     |0
MovieY|2     |0     |1
```

Expected output:

```
"Total 0 count = 3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this, which convert dataframe to boolean for rating equals to zero then to a numpy ndarray and use np.sum which defaults to axis=None summing the entire array:

```
 df.eq(0).values.sum()
```

Output

```
3
```

Answer (score 3):

Two `sum`

```
(df==0).sum().sum()
Out[543]: 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code which gets all data as list of lists (`df.values`), flattens it and filters out only those which are 0. The length of this list returns the number required:

```
def number_of_zeros(df):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x==0, df.values.flatten())))
```

This uses basic python list functions rather than pandas dataframe functions.

Answer (score 2):

- you can use `dataframe.where(dataframe == 0).count()`
- This will return the count of number of zeros in your dataframe
- For more details you can check out the dosumentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html
- The`where` condition returns a dataframe which is the same type as caller with all the rows having zeros and then you just call `.count()` on it
- But with this remember that if there are two zeros in the same row then it will be counted as one zero
- So you can specify the `axis` where you want to look for the condition to be satisfied

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it sounds like you'd like to see a value frequency distribution across all columns, though you are looking for the specific value of zero.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

In [3]: df.values
Out[3]:
array([['batman', 1, 1, 0, 1],
       ['avengers', 2, 2, 1, 2],
       ['hulk', 0, 1, 0, 0],
       ['superman', 1, 1, 2, 1],
       ['ironman', 2, 2, 2, 2]], dtype=object)

In [4]: pd.Series(df.values[:,1:].flatten()).value_counts()
Out[4]:
2    8
1    8
0    4
dtype: int64
```

You can then just leverage the count for the value of 0 for your specific example.

```
pd.Series(df.values[:,1:].flatten()).value_counts()[0]
```

Here's a link to the docs on `value_counts()` and `flatten()`.

- [value_counts()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)
- [flatten()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14/generated/pandas.Index.flatten.html)